# Installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm having a difficult time installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox. After creating the new Virtual Machine, the first boot of Ubuntu goes from a kind of landing page with the ubuntu logo & a swirling thing to a completely black screen, no cursor. I've tried fresh with a few different VMs, all bring me to the same black screen. I've tried with both Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10. My video/graphics settings are 128 MB and VMVSGA (saw this as a potential issue on a few forums). I'm using a Mac with 10.15.7 installed. It's not an M1 mac. Thanks!

Comment: Start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox). If you still need help, please reference the tutorial when asking.

Comment: I've been following the official tutorial, tried a few separate times. Issue starts in Step 3 of the tutorial. When I boot, the screens on the tutorial with the install windows ("verifying installation config," "welcome to Ubuntu") do not appear. Boot goes directly to the black screen with Ubuntu logo, and swirling thing. Instead of then going to the log-in page as it shows in tutorial, it goes to a completely black screen.